# Make react render the closing tag for inputs?

Tags: reactjs

I have an unusual requirement. My site is build with React and I want people to be able to copy the public website's HTML into their own React components.

The only issue that I'm having is inputs do not have a closing tag when rendered by React.

Both of these are valid HTML

```
<input id="input-1" value="foo">
<input id="input-2" value="foo" />
```

However only the 2nd one will work if pasted directly into a React component. Is there a way to force React to render the closing tag for inputs on my site?

Comment: This has nothing to do with how react renders html. The issue is how the browser returns the `innerHTML` (*assuming that is how you copy the html*).

Answer (score 1):

Consider running the copied html source string through a tool like [html tidy](https://www.html-tidy.org/). If you'd like to do the formatting in the browser, consider [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAllADgVxgAhgE8s4BeAHRHgA8Yr8A+EAGhAixnWgGdlQAhgCchEAO4AFYQj4oBAGzECifNgCMhAsAGs4MAMoCAtnAAymOMgBmCnnHWade-Vi2YA5shhCc9kHCM1OAATYJDTASh3HAF3OAAxCCEjARguKOQQATwIVhAACxgjeQB1fPR4HlcwOH0ZCvQANwqiTLAeVRBMOyEYCU13FOtbPwArHhp9D3k4AEUcCHhh+Ts2VyEezMLivKwhTBgS9GCYfOQADgAGNdE7Es0sTL24HsbLNgBHBfh+jlksngAWigcBCITyQjgX3QkP6sSGSBsKz8diM6C8PhR0zgAEE0vs1Hg4BI4EJzCDlqsQDxsfNFpZESM2DABGojiczkgAEzMzToeQeADCECMCP8PAArHkcHYACqs2RIqmNXwASSgYVg+jA+04OI1+mIM0pcAAvqagA). See example below. Good Luck!

```js
  const output = prettier.format("<input type='text' name='username'>", {
    parser: "html",
    plugins: prettierPlugins,
  });

  // Send to server or update your clipboard.
  console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.8.7/standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.8.7/parser-html.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand this correctly, users can post the HTML into your app, and it needs to be rendered as JSX? And the issue you're facing is that users can add non self-closing HTML input tags, but that'll be an issue when rendering JSX (as they need to be self closing)?

You could perform a check to see if the tag being entered is an input, and if it isn't self-closing, and then close it yourself. That would look something like this (assuming you have the field in some var):

```
if(var.substring(1,6) == "input" && var[var.length-2]!="/"){
    var= var.slice(0, var.length-1)+"/"+var[var.length-1]
    }
```